# VSCode / GIT - Colocar no Stage apenas algumas alterações do arquivo?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Utilizando o *VSCODE* + *GIT*, fiz diversas alterações num **mesmo arquivo**, referente a uma implementação necessária.

Para que essa implementações fosse feita, primeiramente foi necessário ajustar/corrigir um código pré existente (já commitado em outro momento), e depois sim aplicar a implementação. Porém, fiz tudo de uma vez, e quando fui gerar o commit da implementação, notei que eu poderia fracionar em diversos commits para ficar mais detalhado em pequenos commits as alterações/correções feitas e outro com a implementação.

Por exemplo, imaginando este é o código abaixo no mesmo arquivo:

```js
// parte do código adaptado/ajustado independente da implementação
function corrigindoMetodoAnterior(params)
{
    // executando alguma ação pertinente
    // ...
}


// referente a uma implementação feita
function implementandoNovoMetodo(params)
{
    // executando alguma ação pertinente
    // ...
}

// conteúdo temporário
function naoCommitarEste(params)
{
    // informações de teste que não é pra commitar
    // ...
}
```

Supondo que todas estas linhas acimas estão como "editadas", sendo que:

- a primeira função `corrigindoMetodoAnterior` já existia, mas sofreu alterações;
- a segunda função `implementandoNovoMetodo` foi adicionada, pois não existia;
- a terceira função `naoCommitarEste` é um método em desenvolvimento que não entrará em nenhum commit;

Então, cada função dessa, quero que esteja em commits distintos:

- "Ajustes da função 'corrigindoMetodoAnterior' para melhor desempenho"
- "Adicionando nova função 'implementandoNovoMetodo' para atender nova demanda"

*E não ter em nenhum commit acima a função 'naoCommitarEste'*

**Existe como fazer isso graficamente direto no *VSCODE* utilizando o *Source Control* do *GIT*, ou apenas por linha de comando?**

---

Equivalente ao que eu quero com linha de comando seria:

```bsh
$ git add -p
```

Será exibido todas as alterações do arquivo, com um menu interativo com algumas opções.

Escolhendo a opção `s` (split), ele vai apresentado cada alteração separadamente.

```
(...)
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,s,e,?]? s
```

Então é só dar `y` (yes) ou `n` (no) para adicionar ou não no commit.

```
(...)
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,K,j,J,g,/,e,?]? y / n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acessando o *StackOverflow* em inglês encontrei a [resposta pra duvida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730585/how-can-i-commit-some-changes-to-a-file-but-not-others-in-vscode) :)

Seguir os passos abaixo:

- Após todas as alterações feitas no arquivo
- Abrir o *Source Control*
- Selecionar o arquivo que eu desejo *commitar* as alterações
- Na janela de comparação das alterações, do lado pós alterado (por padrão o da direita) selecionar apenas as linhas que deseja adicionar no *commit*
- Na parte superior da janela, clicar em (...) (3 pontinhos), e clicar em *Stage Selected Ranges*.

Pronto, só a parte selecionada irá para o *Stage*, mantendo o restante como *Untrack*.
Agora só colocar a mensagem do commit, e partir para o próximo *commit*.

Abaixo um GIF que copiei da resposta original (versão inglês)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]